# Python 2.7 parsing regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7, parsing, web-scraping

So i'm scraping a site and trying to output whatever's between these span tags (it will change depending on what URL I scrape)

```
<span class="inviter-name">tickzapman12345</span>


import urllib2
import re

url = "http://beta.cursevoice.com/join/jt95"
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox') 


response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

matchObj = re.search(r'<span class="inviter-name">(.*?)</span>',str(response))

f = open('output.txt','w')
f.write(str(matchObj))
f.close()
```

However when I check the output file it just says "None", is something wrong with my regex?

Comment: `matchObj = re.search(r'<span class="inviter-name">(.*?)</span>',str(response)).group()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use BeautifulSoup parser instead of regex.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = '<span class="inviter-name">tickzapman12345</span>'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> soup.select('span.inviter-name')[0].text
'tickzapman12345'
```

or

```
matchObj = re.search(r'<span class="inviter-name">(.*?)</span>',response.read())
f = open('output.txt','w')
f.write(matchObj.group(1))
f.close()
```

Comment: I'd like to use regex; I feel as if my code should be working

Comment: What's the value of `response` variable?

Comment: "<addinfourl at 37502368 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x028E01F0>>"

Comment: I get the entire source of the web page

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Any idea how I can just get it to return whatever's inbetween the span tags?